# RPi java run error

Tags: java, terminal

My java -version is 1.8.0. What am I doing wrong, I cant run my basic hello world gui without this as I'm trying to use it similar to a "kiosk" with no desktop environment and JUST this.

> Error: missing 'server' JVM at '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/arm/server/libjvm.so'.
>   Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.
>   E: /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore exited with code 1.
>   done.
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>   ca-certificates-java
>   openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf
>   openjdk-8-jre:armhf
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running from a RaspberryPi and the jdk is headless then you can not create a gui on the py without doing it remote... but you can run an remote Xserver and display a GUI on that.

Swing applications are headfull so to speak and need a graphical interface. This will not work unless you pipe it over an X enabled ssh connection to another machine with an XServer. As you are trying to start a Swing appliation in a console without a Graphical interface is will surely fail.

Comment: im not trying to do that.what i am trying to do is make the linux boot into terminal and run a single java file.

I do not want the [x][_] stuff you see. i want no borders.

Comment: Well that gives lots more info :-) I see armhf which implies arm based processor and often this is a RPi (assumption indeed) and you are talking about a gui, so what do you expect without more info? So tell us what are you trying to do :-) and provide some code maybe?

Comment: right now i cant get a basic hello world to work.

import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
public class helloWorld{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello world");
    }
}

Comment: what i am trying to do is for the pi to load no other programs but this one java file. Ofcourse loading kernel and other neccessary

When you load it in windows or the desktop environment you see a header bar with close minimize or maximize. i want that to be gone completely. I also dont want the desktop environment loaded either.

But i am aware that there may be some issues with that seeing as how i may have to load a few extra things in order to draw the gui. i just cant figure out what.

I was finally able to resolve the initial error but im getting a headerless error now.

Comment: A JOptionPane and the like are part of swing and therefore NOT headless. Swing applications need an X like environmet (a desktop) to work. so if you want hello world don't use a gui in a headless environment .. good luck

Comment: then is there a way to hide the desktop completely? OR is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry you are lossing me. I don't understand what you are asking. Try to be very specific please ...

Comment: Ok.This is what i am trying to do.

I am trying to set up a pi to be mainly used witha  touchscreen to run a simple buy/sell program with the blockchain api.

I do not want any type of desktop because it will not be used for that.

I want the device to boot up and only run the java file. This java file has screens with buttons people can touch for options. I do not want any borders and i want the entire screen filed with just this program. no top bar no access to anything else but that one program.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I have given answer to your first question. We are going way of topic on this question. By the way I would guess that you do want a graphical interface if you want a touch screen to handle button presses and the like. Good luck with it.